# Only the first part of this loop is working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My job is to make an automatic browser bot.

I tried this code to do what I need.

```
// first finding and selecting button
var Select = document.getElementsByClassName('Login');
Select[0].click();
// second finding and selecting button
var Select2 = document.getElementsByClassName('OK');
Select2[0].click();
```

Let me explain this code for you.This code is trying to find a button which class's name is 'Login' and then it will click on that button.After that a new window will appear.Next this code will try to find another button in that new window and click on the that.

Ok.
This code is fine and it has no problem since i want to put this inside a loop to make every thing automatic.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // first finding and selecting button
  var Select = document.getElementsByClassName('Login');
  Select[0].click();
  // second finding and selecting button
  var Select2 = document.getElementsByClassName('OK');
  Select2[0].click();
}
```

Well now when i run this code,for the first time it will be executed very well but there will be no second time.And the console of browser shows this to me:

[image: My problem]

The first time all of the code will be executed but for the second time only the first finding and clicking on button will be done.
When the new window appears, my code is not working anymore and it sucks and the second finding and clicking on button will not happen.

These are the properties of the second button :

```
    <button type="button" class="OK" ng-click="OK()">
        <i class="btnIcon"></i>
        confirm
    </button>
```

Comment: What does clicking on the second button do?

Comment: That will send/post an order to server.

Comment: If it submits a form, that reloads the page and your script stops.

Comment: No that never reload the page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @mehdirajabi You said this code works good for 1 time. Why do you need to run such "login" code 5 times in a loop? What to you expect?

Comment: well Anton, it's not important that why i need to login for 5 times. This problem can happen for every programmer and i think if i can clean the cache after i run this script this will be fixed and the loop will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found the solution.That website was not allowing me to run a Java Script code when that code is using cache files.The code was ok!